# Is it possible to store, or pre-define a LINQ query for re-use?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have a linq query that i use about 5 times within the same MVC class, is it possible to define the query somewhere within the page in the same way you can `public const` a `string` or an `int`, without having to create a method which calls the linq query?

i.e.

```
const LinqQuery myQuery = from cat in db.Categories where cat.CategoryID != null select cat;

...

public ActionResult Edit(long id = 0)
{
    ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = myQuery;
    ...
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = myQuery;
    ...
}
```

From what i can see, the only way is creating a method, but i would like to avoid it if there is a nicer way of doing things.

Comment: I assume you mean you want to re-execute it with an updated db.Categories every time? Otherwise you could just store the result directly.

Comment: yes, i would like it to be re-executed every time as the result set can change

Comment: you need the db context. why not create a static method instead?

Comment: Obviously, you can't store a linq query as a constant, just like you can't have something like `const int a = b * 2;` Because, obviously, a variable cannot be a constant.

But, the right way of doing what you want to do is to create a Repository class and define your query as a method of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that Linq queries are only executed when you iterate over the result so:

```
static List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
static IEnumerable<int> result = from i in list where i > 2 select i;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Sum()); // 3
    list.Add(5);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Sum()); // 8
}
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't deal with the fact that he doesn't have a dbcontext when first defining the query.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Has an article on precompiled queries:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx

In your example it could look something like this:

```
public static readonly Func<MyContext, int, IQueryable<Category>>
    myQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((MyContext db, int categoryID) =>
            from cat in db.Categories where cat.CategoryID == categoryID select cat);
```

I added `readonly` as it is going to be the closest you'll get to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just put it in the constructor (I assume the type of `db.Catagories` is `Catagory`)

```
public class ClassName
{
    public ClassName()
    {
        db =  //do whatever is needed to initialize the db context
        myQuery = from cat in db.Categories where cat.CategoryID != null select cat;
    }

    DataSourceContext db;
    IQueryable<Catagory> myQuery;

    public ActionResult Edit(long id = 0)
    {
        ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = myQuery;
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = myQuery;
        ...
    }
}
```

This could also be done in the static constructor with static members if access to `db` is done in a thread safe manner (via internally inside `DataSourceContext` or by you in defensive coding)

---

However a better way would be to call a static function that returns the query you want and passing in the context of the database you want to connect to.

```
public static IQueryable<Catagory> NonNullCatagoriesQuery(DataSourceContext db)
{
    return from cat in db.Categories where cat.CategoryID != null select cat;
}
```

Then in your code you just do

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id = 0)
{
    ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = NonNullCatagoriesQuery(db);
    ...
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = NonNullCatagoriesQuery(db);
    ...
}
```

You also could move the function in to a repository class that held the db context too so you would not need to pass it in, but you did not include in your code example how you got `db`.

Comment: This is not a good solution. The query should be in a Repository class.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, sorta, While it's similar, you can declare a [Func<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and call that. It looks cleaner / nicer than a method when you only have a very simple instruction you want to execute.

Here's sorta an example on their implementation (This is from a project where I had to use SetWindowPos multiple times along with some other stuff):

```
Func<Process, winPosData, bool> swp = (p, w) => SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)w.hWndInsertAfter, w.x, w.y, w.cx, w.cy, w.uFlags);
```